# how can i make R system reorganize this tibble

Tags: r, pivot, tibble

i have this table

```
df <- tibble(
  club = c("Avai", "Figueirense"),
  "2019_revenue" = runif(min = 100, max =300, n = 2),
  "2018_revenue" = runif(min = 100, max =300, n = 2),
  "2017_revenue" = runif(min = 100, max =300, n = 2),
  "2019_division" = c("A","B"),
  "2018_division" = c("B","B"),
  "2017_division" = c("A","B")
)
```

and i want to reorganize this, so the coluns can be "club","year", "revenue" and "division", in this order. whant can i do to make this? can i use pivot_longer?

Answer (score 1):

We can capture the characters before of after `_` in the column names with `names_pattern` and use that in `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -club, names_to = c("year", ".value"), 
        names_pattern = "(\\d+)_(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  club        year  revenue division
  <chr>       <chr>   <dbl> <chr>   
1 Avai        2019     128. A       
2 Avai        2018     178. B       
3 Avai        2017     214. A       
4 Figueirense 2019     291. B       
5 Figueirense 2018     154. B       
6 Figueirense 2017     282. B
```

---

Or may also use `names_sep`

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -club, names_to = c("year", ".value"), names_sep = "_")
```